# SpreadsheetLight: set Worksheet Zoom Level

Tags: c#, excel, spreadsheetlight

Using SpreadsheetLight (SSL) in C#.
I'm creating a spreadsheet as a result of a long SQL process.
The result set, when zoomed to 100% (the default) is too wide and all my users are instantly zooming down to 80%.

I don't see a way in SSL to set the worksheet (or workbook) zoom level in code.

I tried looking for a way to set the zoom level in the document, and the worksheet, but nothing with the word ZOOM seems to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following.

```cs
using var document = new SLDocument();
// perform work
document.SetPageSettings(new SLPageSettings() { ZoomScale = 80 });
```

ZoomScale range 10% to 400%